# Typical error of underlying process

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, standard-deviation

Considering underlying process (of some signal with number of samples $N$ and standard deviation $\sigma$) in [DSP guide book, page 18](http://www.dspguide.com/ch2/2.htm), the definition of its typical error is following:

$$Typ.err = \frac{\sigma}{N^{1/2}}$$

my question is why so?

I didn't find in the book the explanation of this equation.

Answer (score 1):

This section describes estimation of the mean of an underlying process. Consider i.i.d. samples $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Then,
$$
\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
is an estimator of $\mu$. Note that
$$
\mathsf{E}\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf{E}X_i=\mu,
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}.
$$
The "typical error" is just $\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_n)}=\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: thank you! according to the book, I thought that the variance is just $\sigma^2$, but from your notes it is $(x_i-\mu)^2$, I'm a bit confused about the definition of it.

Comment: The variance of $X_i$ is $\sigma^2=\mathsf{E}[X_i-\mu]^2$.

Comment: ok, and why do you divide by $n^2$ in the equation for the variance of $\overline{X}_n$?

Comment: If $c$ is a constant and $X$ is a random variable, $\operatorname{Var}(cX)=c^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$. Also, if $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, $\operatorname{Var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\operatorname{Var}(X_1)+\cdots+\operatorname{Var}(X_n)$.

Comment: so, you just divided by $n^2$ at will? it's a bit unclear, maybe because I don't exactly get the difference between $\bar{X}_n$ and estimator of $\bar{X}_n$

Comment: Hmmm. $\bar{X}_n$ is an estimator of $\mu$, which is centered around $\mu$. As $n$ increases, estimation errors becomes small, which is captured by its variance. Also note that
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\ldots
$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused about "correct" definition of variance, here: http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/1.htm at page 18 the author defines it as $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(X_i-\mu)$ (which is the same as in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)), but you tell me that I should divide by $n^2$ instead of $n$

Comment: It is the sample variance of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ as opposed to the variance of a random variable.